# Error in undefined symbols for architecture

Tags: ios

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_Ending_lat", referenced from:
      -[MapKitDragAndDropViewController calculator:] in MapKitDragAndDropViewController.o
      -[MapKitDragAndDropViewController viewDidLoad] in MapKitDragAndDropViewController.o
  "_Ending_log", referenced from:
      -[MapKitDragAndDropViewController calculator:] in MapKitDragAndDropViewController.o
      -[MapKitDragAndDropViewController viewDidLoad] in MapKitDragAndDropViewController.o
  "_Starting_lat", referenced from:
      -[MapKitDragAndDropViewController calculator:] in MapKitDragAndDropViewController.o
      -[MapKitDragAndDropViewController viewDidLoad] in MapKitDragAndDropViewController.o
  "_Starting_log", referenced from:
      -[MapKitDragAndDropViewController calculator:] in MapKitDragAndDropViewController.o
      -[MapKitDragAndDropViewController viewDidLoad] in MapKitDragAndDropViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the error I am getting please help me with this.

Comment: have you included mapkit framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can found these type of error if your class `.m` not listed under the `Compile Sources` OR missing frameworks. As i think You forgot to link the `MapKit framework` with your `iOS` project.

Comment: i have added map kit in my application

Comment: `Clean` the project hope it will help you